# PHP: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::SELECT

Tags: php, mysqli

Okay I asked a question last week.  I got a few answers, several which did not help; however, I decided to recheck all of my connections.  That did resolve some problems after I had to check here to make it function.  Next was for some reason I did not check my query to make sure it worked in mysql.  I also noticed that my version has a way to output the query into PHP code which I did.  Now I am stuck with the error code:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::SELECT tblConference.colConferenceName, tblSchool.colSchoolName, tblSchool.colClass, tblSurface.colSurfaceName, tblSurface.colSurfaceCompany, tblStadium.colStadiumName, tblStadium.colAddress, tblStadium.colCity, tblStadium.colRegion, tblStadium.colCounty, tblStadium.colCapacity FROM tblStadium, tblConference, tblSurface, tblSchool, tblStadiumSchool WHERE tblConference.colConferenceID = tblSchool.colConferenceID AND tblSurface.colSurfaceID = tblStadium.colSurfaceID AND tblStadium.colStadiumID = tblStadiumSchool.colStadiumID AND tblSchool.colSchoolID = tblStadiumSchool.colSchoolID AND tblSchool.colSchoolName LIKE \'A%\' ORDER BY tblSchool.colSchoolName() in C:\xampp\htdocs\stadium\alpha\a.php on line 24

Now here is my new code, I will try to make it look halfway decently,

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbstadium");
    /* check connection */
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error);
        exit();
        }
    /* your sql query */
```

> $sql = "SELECT tblConference.colConferenceName, tblSchool.colSchoolName, tblSchool.colClass, tblSurface.colSurfaceName, tblSurface.colSurfaceCompany, tblStadium.colStadiumName, tblStadium.colAddress, tblStadium.colCity, tblStadium.colRegion, tblStadium.colCounty, tblStadium.colCapacity FROM tblStadium, tblConference, tblSurface, tblSchool, tblStadiumSchool WHERE tblConference.colConferenceID = tblSchool.colConferenceID AND tblSurface.colSurfaceID = tblStadium.colSurfaceID AND tblStadium.colStadiumID = tblStadiumSchool.colStadiumID AND tblSchool.colSchoolID = tblStadiumSchool.colSchoolID AND tblSchool.colSchoolName LIKE \'A%\' ORDER BY tblSchool.colSchoolName";

```
/* query your db */
if ($result = $mysqli->$sql($sql)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
    { /* display row */    
        echo '<p>School Name: ' . $row['colSchoolName'] . '</br>Conference: ' . $row['colConferenceName'] . '</br>Class: ' . $row['colClass'] . '</br>Stadium Name: ' . $row['colStadiumName'] . '</br>Address: ' . $row['colAddress'] . '</br>City: ' . $row['colCity'] . '</br>County: ' . $row['colCounty'] . '</br>Region: ' . $row['colRegion'] . '</br>Capacity: ' . $row['colCapacity'] . '</br>Surface Type: ' . $row['colSurfaceName'] . '</br>Surface Company: ' . $row['colSurfaceCompany'] . '</br>Year Installed: ' . $row['colSurfaceYear'] . '</p>';
    }
    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
```

Now I am not sure what the issue is.  I been trying to get this to work.  BTW just so you know the query and connection should not be an issue.  If their is something I am missing just let me know.

Comment: mysqli is not enabled in your php install.

Comment: undefined **method** mysqli? This is not right: `$mysqli->$sql($sql)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is your problem:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->$sql($sql)) {
```

You're basically calling a method with the same name as your SQL statement, i.e. `SELECT tblConference [...]`. Such a method doesn't exist, obviously. Rather, try [`mysqli::query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
```

By the way, another error is in this line:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc())
```

`$sql` is still your SQL statement. What you want is to iterate over the [`mysqli_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, which you've put into the variable `$result`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

Comment: That eliminated the error but now I just get the <h1> tag and thats it.  I did not include that is it is outside of the <? tags.  Needless to say the results do not show.

Comment: `<h1>` tag? Where? I don't see any in your question. Could you please rephrase what youre trying to ask, as I have a hard time unterstanding it. Also, I have found another error in your code and updated my answer.

Comment: I get nothing displayed on the screen.  I know the query works as I checked it on my XAMMP phpMySQL admin console.  So my question is why wont it display the query results.

Comment: BTW I had one error in my output.  For some reason I have not put in the year the surface was installed and as a result it caused some errors when I had it my query.  I did find that error before I posted the question however I did not catch the output was also going to place that in there.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you haven't corrected the part that I added to my answer yet. Maybe your database is empty. Maybe your query just resturns zero rows. Maybe there's another mistake somewhere in your code. Maybe the browser hiccups because of the `</br>` (sic!) tags. I cannot debug your whole script here.

Comment: I was just thinking where I am putting values into $result.  I do not see anything outside of the if statement.  Is that an issue?

Comment: Well thanks for your help.  At least now I have a page without errors.  I can search for the output solution as that seems easier.  :D

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dbstadium");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { // check connection
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error);
    exit();
}
    // your sql query 
    $sql = "SELECT tblConference.colConferenceName, tblSchool.colSchoolName, tblSchool.colClass, tblSurface.colSurfaceName, tblSurface.colSurfaceCompany, tblStadium.colStadiumName, tblStadium.colAddress, tblStadium.colCity, tblStadium.colRegion, tblStadium.colCounty, tblStadium.colCapacity FROM tblStadium, tblConference, tblSurface, tblSchool, tblStadiumSchool WHERE tblConference.colConferenceID = tblSchool.colConferenceID AND tblSurface.colSurfaceID = tblStadium.colSurfaceID AND tblStadium.colStadiumID = tblStadiumSchool.colStadiumID AND tblSchool.colSchoolID = tblStadiumSchool.colSchoolID AND tblSchool.colSchoolName LIKE \'A%\' ORDER BY tblSchool.colSchoolName";
        if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { // query your db
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object())// fetch object
            {  // display row    
                echo "<p><div>School Name: {$row->colSchoolName}</div><div>Conference: {$row->colConferenceName}</div><div>Class: {$row->colClass}</div><div>Stadium Name: {$row->colStadiumName}</div><div>Address: {$row->colAddress}</div><div>City: {$row->colCity}</div><div>County: {$row->colCounty}</div><div>Region: {$row->colRegion}</div><div>Capacity: {$row->colCapacity}</div><div>Surface Type: {$row->colSurfaceName}</div><div>Surface Company: {$row->colSurfaceCompany}</div><div>Year Installed: {$row->colSurfaceYear}</div></p>";
            }//end while loop
            $result->free(); // free result set
        }//end if
$mysqli->close(); // close connection
```

Comment: I did this fix although I am now seeing no errors YAY!, but I am seeing no information BOO :(  I am not sure what is going on.  I am testing this in xampp so I am not sure if XAMPP is the issue or not.  If you have any other ideas let me know.